# Outlook Redemption and Citrix UPM VHD

Tags: outlook-redemption

We have implemented Citrix user profile management with a VHD for the Outlook OST and Search files to prevent duplicate OST files getting created.

One of our apps uses Redemption to send emails but users are reporting issues where they are getting Outbox not found errors.

Does redemption support Citrix VHD for the Outlook profile?

Comment: That does not sounds like an error coming from Redemption. What is the exact error message? What is the relevant snippet of you code that raises the exception?

Comment: Our application uses version 5.16.0.4972
Error when the user tries and sends an email -
Error ccurred while accessing component property/method:
GetDefaultFolder
Catastophic Failure
Error Code 0x80020009 Proclaim/mapimail.p 5890

Its a case management application running on Oracle OpenEdge using redemption for the Outlook integation.

Comment: Please send an email to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com and I will send you the debug version of Redemption.